# Android Java Project Converts to Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I want to convert my java project to Kotlin, there are more than 500 java files. How can I convert it into Kotlin easily?

I know that we can convert one by one java file to Kotlin, But there are many files.

Can I convert it at once?

Comment: You can convert it all at once, BUT don't expect it to compile immediately :D

Comment: Try to keep old file and add Kotlin for new files only, 500 files to convert ... Good luck

Comment: So the transition from Java to Kotlin is seamless but not straightforward if the project is complex

Comment: I tried for my app ... that has alot of files/classes. Converter ran for a while and then just disappeared. No feedback :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can definitely try. You just need to select a module or a folder in the `Project navigator` and select `Code --> Convert Java file to Kotlin file`:

[image: Convert complete module to Kotlin]

You, though, need to keep in mind that the conversion is not perfect. For instance, Android Studio will have to guess whether a whole lot of properties are nullable or not. It will not get them all right... you will get a lot of crashes.

My suggestion would be to batch files in sensible chunks, so you can fix those Kotlinized files without getting swamped with errors.

Note: after converting a file to Kotlin you still will need to review it. A lot of things will be kept in Java for the sake of safety, but now that you have Kotlin you can use collection extensions, default constructor parameters, ...

Comment: WHY MY ANDROID STUDIO DOESNT HAVE THE Convert Java file to Kotlin file

Comment: @VasantRaval Shouting... 
Did you buy a refurbished version? It might be faulty?

Comment: I can able to to convert my entire project at once so I have convert every individual file

Answer (score 3):

1. Select your **app** folder and go to Code  **`Convert Java File to Kotlin File`**
2. Then after you convert the file,it says **`kotlin not configured`**.Click the **`Configure`** text then select the type of module you want to apply kotlin and it comes with the latest kotlin version press **ok**

**N.B After you convert the code,you must convert some parameters that the compiler found it as a warning or error message.**

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, android-studio will do most of the work for you. To convert the existing javacode into kotlin, simply select the src/main/java folder in the project and choose Code->“Convert Java File to Kotlin File”. Android studio will then try as best as it can to convert all your java-code to kotlin-code.